# PHP code to determine if a user was 301 redirected to my site

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, http-headers, http-status-code-301

Is it possible in PHP to know if a user has been 301 redirected to my website?

So in **myoldsite.com** I have a 301 redirect in the .htaccess file to **mynewsite.com**.

Can I place some PHP code in **mynewsite.com** to recognise when a user has been 301 redirected? I just need this to display a specific message if this is the case.

Many thanks for any pointers here :-)

Comment: @SalmanA: the cookie would only be visible by the old site, unless he did some XSS specifically to read it.

Comment: Can't you do this with `get_headers()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe with 301-redirects the `HTTP_REFERER` field will contain the *original* referer:

- User enters oldsite.com in address bar and 301 redirected to newsite.com

  - referer = ""
- User is visiting 3rdparty.com, clicks a link pointing to oldsite.com and 301 redirected to newsite.com

  - referer = "3rdparty.com"

This behavior somewhat makes sense for 301 redirects.

Solution: I think you should add a query-string parameter to your 301 response such as `ref=oldsite` and check its value on your new website.

If you are concerned about having query string parameters in your URLs, you can tell search engines to ignore specific query string parameters. The procedure varies with search engines. Apparently there is a trick that works across all major search engines: the [`<link rel="canonical">`](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394) tag. Examples:

- `http://newsite.com/?ref=oldsite`

  - `http://newsite.com/`
- `http://newsite.com/?ref=oldsite&page=main` and
- `http://newsite.com/?page=main&ref=oldsite`

  - `http://newsite.com/?page=main`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Salman :-) So my .htaccess could read: `RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 /index.php?ref=oldsite http://www.newsite.com/` And on 'newsite.com' have a script that checks for ref equals oldsite?

Comment: Yes the idea is right but not sure about the syntax of `Rewrite`, perhaps it should be `Redirect 301 /index.php http://newsite.com/?ref=oldsite`

Comment: That was supposed to be "Now to tell...". Out of intersest, how do I achieve this in Webmaster Tools?

Comment: A cross-search-engine way to tell search engines that they should ignore the `ref=whatever` parameter is to use the [link rel="canonical"](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394) tag. The canonical URL of the main page of newsite.com would be *newsite.com plus (query string minus ref=whatever if there was a query string)*

Comment: Perfect. I'm now using (pseudo code) `if ($script == index.php) then <link rel="canonical" href="http://www.newsite.com/" /> end if`. Is this good to go?

Comment: Can I add "ref" to the Google Webmaster Tools "URL Parameters" field too?

Comment: Aaaah cool :-) Many thanks for all your help and patience with this. Very much appreciate it and have learned lots. Thanks.

Comment: Answer accepted :-) Will quality control some comments shortly.