# How to detect 301 redirect using php

Tags: php, .htaccess, seo, http-status-code-301

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to identify if referrer is a 301 redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963328/how-to-identify-if-referrer-is-a-301-redirect)

Using htaccess Im doing a 301 redirect to redirect old urls to the new urls, the issue is the url contains the id that is stored in the db. But I have a new db with new ids so now when the old url redirects to the new url a different record loads on the page. So what I did was store the old ids along with the new ids so I know what old id belongs to the new id. However how can I detect someone is trying to access the old url? Is there a way in php to detect the person coming to the page is being redirected via a 301? I dont want to add anything new to the url due to SEO reasons so I really need to know if I can detect if they came to this page via 301 redirect. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: you can work with $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; but this is not really reliable

Comment: @FlorianKasper: even if `HTTP_REFERER` is set it will point to the page where the link was clicked, not the script that sent 301. Such is the case with 301s.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496522/php-code-to-determine-if-a-user-was-301-redirected-to-my-site/9496657#9496657

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add another parameter to the redirect like `redirect=true`, check the param to let your app know it was a redirect, start the session, and then redirect again to the final, unaltered url, compare the session to know, that a user came from the redirected url.

Or do what Salman says, use a canonical url.

Comment: As mentioned in my original notes I cant due to SEO reasons.

Comment: That's why you redirect again! For the SEO reasons, the final url will have no additional param but your app will know.

Comment: You can tell search engines about your canonical URL via `<link rel=canonical>`. Use this to tell search engines that `?redirect=true` can be ignored.

Comment: What's the point of the session? Besides that this is exactly the same concept as my answer.

Comment: The point of the session is to actually transfer the knowledge about the redirect into the app. Otherwise it's just another redirect and can come from whoever.

Comment: @markus-tharkun I gotcha. I assumed that the point of letting the application know that it was a redirect was to pull the correct product from the database.

Answer (score 0):

A script won't know that something has been redirected to it or not. Instead of redirecting to, say `index.php?id=12345` add an intermediate redirect where you can determine the proper URL.

First, redirect in your .htaccess using a temporary variable name, e.g. `index.php?oldid=12345` and then in that script do:

```
if (isset($_POST['oldid'])) {
    $id = fetch_new_id();
    header("Location: index.php?id=$id");
}
```

Comment: how does this affect SEO and passing the "juice" via 301 redirects twice? As I would need to do 2 301 redirects in your suggestion.

Comment: An extra 301 redirect isn't going to affect your SEO at all.

Answer (score 0):

i think you cannot detect http status that was set, but using .htaccess you can add additional variable to redirected urls or rename id to another variable name.

Answer (score 0):

Why not handle all the old URLs via php plus a rewrite and make the code directly 301 redirect to the new URL with the new id?